# SWT: No more Control handles

Tags: java, swt

Using eclipse, I have created a Form Editor with 2 tabs for my application. One tab is for GUI support and the other one is for normal text editor. In the GUI page, I have been using hundreds of SWT controls such as tables, sections, buttons, etc.

The problem is when I opened more than 20 files with the Form Editor in my application, I get an exception "SWT: No more handles". I could understand that there is no more control handles for the controls to be created to the Form Editor. I could check the control handles availability and proceed to open the file, if enough handles are available. Otherwise i can not open the file itself.

Is there any possible way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may well have reached the limit. Note that the number of handles varies a lot between platforms (macOS, Linux, Windows) so if you plan to run this on different platforms you need to test on all of them.

If you are using SWT classes derived from `Resource` (`Color`, `Font`, `Image`, `Cursor`, ....) then you must call `dispose` on the object when you are done with it. Failing to do so will leak handles.

You should also try to share these resources - for example don't create a new `Color` each time. Use a manager class that handles sharing the colors, the manager class can also handle disposing of the resources.

JFace provides manager classes such as `ColorRegistry`, `FontRegistry` and `ImageRegistry` which might be useful.

If this is not enough you will have reduce this large number of controls, perhaps you could use pop-up dialogs to show some of the information when buttons are pressed.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: When we try to open more number of manifest files (around 80 files) with multi-page editor in eclipse, the same exception (No more handles) occurs and the eclipse itself crashes.

Comment: As I said there is a limit on the number of handles which can't be worked around. Careful management of resources makes sure you don't hit the limit earlier than is necessary but on some platforms you will eventually hit the limit.

Comment: Is there any way to find the availability of Control Handles left? So that i can inform the users a warning message that there is no control handles.

Comment: Not that I know of. This is very platform dependent, on my Mac I don't think there is a limit.

Comment: Finally, I just handled this situation with the own manager class which is used to dispose the controls of the editor page once the editor page is de-activated or hidden behind other editors. I believe that this won't create the SWT exception ever even on any platforms like Windows, Linux, etc...